Order the choice column of a sharepoint list when a user selects the choices out of order
I have a multiple selection column in a SharePoint list that has eleven options. If a user selects any of the eleven selections is there a way to order them in a certain order when they submit the form?
ex.) the selection options are A, B, C, and D. The user selects D, B, A, C in that order. I would like the entry in the list to show their selection as A, B, C, D and not the order they selected each option.

No. This is an unordered list.
Maybe you should have 11 fields and all of them have options A-B-C-D, or have 4 fields (A, B, C, D) and all of them have options 1-11.
Big flaw of this method, that you can't force to have different answers in the fields.
It's easier and cleaner with a canvas app.
